# Duplicate Sprite in Random Positions with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a game with Swift and SpriteKit and I'd like to create multiple instances of the same sprite in random positions, but I can't figure out how to do it. I considered just doing adding this code:
`addChild(object)`
 multiple times, but this causes the app to crash. How can I solve my problem?

EDIT:  I've fixed this part of the problem, but now I want to add my random sprites in random X locations. I've tried to generate random positions by executing this code: 
    `var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(8) 
    crateDuplicate.position = (CGPointMake(randomNumber, 200))`
But, I get an error of "Cannot assign a value of type '(CGPoint)' to a value of type 'CGPoint'." What should I do?

Comment: If you want better results here, please post some code of what you have tried. You wil find people will respond better and might be able to help you.

Comment: Use arc4random to pick x,y positions at random. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform Then add each node instance.

Comment: How do I add an instance?

Comment: @kriskendalll99 You can create copies of same sprite by using copy() method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30848951/3402095

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That worked! However, I'm having a problem assigning my sprite to a random position. I'm getting the error: "Cannot assign a value of type '(CGPoint)' to a value of type 'CGPoint'." Here's my code: `var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(8)
        crateDuplicate.position = (CGPointMake(randomNumber, 200))` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @kriskendall99 I can't produce what you are saying. Please update your question (not paste the code in the comments because its not readable like that) with full code which can produce described error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
let randomNumber = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(8))
position = CGPointMake(randomNumber, 200)
```

`arc4random_uniform` returns an UInt32 and you need a CGFloat, so you need to convert it. Also skip the () around `CGPointMake` otherwise you'll create a tuple.

For more ways of getting random numbers and other useful stuff, have a look at this collection of utility classes and functions by the Ray Wenderlich team: https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils